# Gradient of a function and inverse of metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, information-geometry

Having some knowledge in differential geometry on $\mathbb{R}^n$, I'm reading a book on Information geometry by Amari. Let $S=\{p_{\theta}\}$, $\theta=(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n)$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold parameterized by $\theta$. At some point the author writes, for a (differentiable) funtion $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$, 
$$(\text{grad}~f)_p=\sum_{i,j}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_i}\right)_pg^{i,j}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}\right)_p,$$ where $[g^{i,j}]$  is the inverse of the Riemannian metric $[g_{i,j}]=[\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\rangle]$. Can someone explain how does one arrive at this expression? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure of your formula? The gradient is a vector, so you should specify a component on the l.h.s. and do not sum over 2 indices on the r.h.s. (Amari's book is great)

Comment: @Avitus Yes, this is how it is given in the book. I too had the same doubt. In the next line he writes $\|(df)_p\|_p^2=\|(\text{grad}~f)_p\|_p^2=(\partial_if)_p(\partial_jf)_pg^{i,j}(p)$. I don't understand this as well.

Comment: I see...that object is not the gradient of $f$ at $p$, understood as the vector $\nabla(f)^k:=\sum_i g^{ki}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta^i}$. It is $\operatorname{grad}(f):=\sum_k \nabla(f)^k\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_k}$, instead (i.e. an element of $T_pM$ with components given by the gradient of $f$ at $p$ components)...

Comment: ...the identity involving the norms comes from  $\|v\|^2:=\langle v,v\rangle$, where the inner product is defined using the Riemannian metric as you stated in the question.

Comment: @Avitus: I don't understand. How does the inverse of the metric come into picture? Can you explain in detail in the answer?

Comment: How do you define the gradient?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang: The author first defines the differential of $f$ at $p$ as an element of $T_p^*(S)$ which maps $X\mapsto X(f)$, and then $(\text{grad}~f)_p$ as the tangent vector corresponding to $(df)_p$.

Comment: @Ashok the inverse of the Riemannian metric is in the definition of the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, the gradient of a function $f$ is defined as its dual vector of $df$, we can immediately write
$$(\mathrm{grad} f(p))^i=g^{ij}(df(p))_j$$

> **Proof:**  $$g_{ij}X^j=\left<\partial_i,\partial_j\right>X^j=\left<\partial_i,X^j\partial_j\right>=\left<\partial_i,X\right>=X_i$$

And we know $df(p)_j=\partial_j f(p)$, so it follows
$$\mathrm{grad} f(p)=(\mathrm{grad} f(p))^i\partial_i=g^{ij}\partial_jf(p)\partial_i$$

Comment: Can you elaborate bit on how you get $(\mathrm{grad} f(p))^i=g^{ij}(df(p))_j$? It should be simple, I presume. So give me only a hint!

Comment: @Ashok See my edit.

Comment: Sorry, still I'm not getting the appearence of the inverse $g^{i,j}$.

Comment: @Ashok $g^{ij}$ is the inverse of $g_{ij}$

Comment: Yes, I know. But, will this equation $g_{ij}X^j=\langle\partial_i,\partial_j\rangle X^j=\langle\partial_i,X^j\partial_j\rangle=\langle\partial_i,X\rangle=X_i$ be true even if we replace $g_{i,j}$ by its inverse $g^{i,j}$? I'm confused.

Comment: @Ashok No, do not replace. Multiplicate both sides by the inverse metric.

Comment: $(df)_p$ is an element of $T_p^*(S)$, right? So, how can we write $(\mathrm{grad} f(p))^i=g^{ij}(df(p))_j$?

Comment: @Ashok grad$f(p)$ and $df(p)$ are dual to each other according to you definition. $X^i\partial_i$ and $X_idx^i$ are dual similarly.